# Grails GORM using immutable embedded object

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, grails-orm, grails-2.0

I have a GORM class which is using an embedded instance in it. And the embedded instance is an immutable class. When I try to start the app, it is throwing the setter property is not found exception.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a setter for property amount in class com.xxx.Money.
```

This is my GORM class:

```
class Billing {
    static embedded = ['amount']
    Money amount
}
```

And Money is defined as immutable:

```
final class Money {
    final Currency currency
    final BigDecimal value

    Money(Currency currency, BigDecimal value) {
        this.currency = currency
        this.value = value
    }
}
```

Anyway to resolve this without making Money mutable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grails and hibernate generally need full domain classes to be mutable to support all the features hibernate provides.

Rather than embedding a Money domain class, you can store the Money amount with a multi-column hibernate UserType.  Here's an example of how to write the UserType:

```
import java.sql.*
import org.hibernate.usertype.UserType

class MoneyUserType implements UserType {

    int[] sqlTypes() {
        [Types.VARCHAR, Types.DECIMAL] as int[]
    }

    Class returnedClass() {
        Money
    }

    def nullSafeGet(ResultSet resultSet, String[] names, Object owner)  HibernateException, SQLException {
        String currency = resultSet.getString(names[0])
        BigDecimal value = resultSet.getBigDecimal(names[1])
        if (currency != null && value != null) {
            new Money(currency, value)
        } else {
            new Money("", 0.0)
        }
    }

    void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement statement, Object money, int index) {
        statement.setString(index, money?.currency ?: "")
        statement.setBigDecimal(index+1, money?.value ?: 0.0)
    }

    ...

}
```

To use it in a domain class, map the field to the UserType instead of embedding it:

```
class Billing {
    static mapping = {
        amount type: MoneyUserType
    }
    Money amount
}
```

Comment: All example of a MoneyUserType I've found all look the same, they all implement the same 4 methods and leave out the remaining needed methods simply using ... instead. Will you improve your answer by providing a full example of the MoneyUserType that allows mutable values?